# Hibernate deleteing parent with out deleteing a child

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi could anyone please explain me about how to delete the parent with deleting the child's.For example When I have an entity called Class and Student.Here the parent is class and child is student.I want to delete the parent(Class) with out deleting Child as student.In Hibernate.

**ClassEntity**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.myapp.struts;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

/**
 *
 * @author hyva
 */
@Entity
public class Calss implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)   
    @JoinColumn(name = "CalssId")        
    private Set<Student> student = new HashSet();

    public boolean addstudent(Student s){
    return student.add(s);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Calss)) {
            return false;
        }
        Calss other = (Calss) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.myapp.struts.Calss[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public void setStudent(Set<Student> student) {
        this.student = student;
    }



}
```

**Student**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.myapp.struts;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author hyva
 */
@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String studentname;
    private String age;

    public String getStudentname() {
        return studentname;
    }

    public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student other = (Student) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.myapp.struts.Student[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi could anyone please help me.

Comment: can you share your mapping details here ?

Comment: Hi Here I have posted two entity's One employee and phone number,What I needed is I delete the Employee i don't want to delete the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

An object has different types of associations. For example composite association in which their will be a parent object and which will control one or many child/dependent objects.  The **dependent objects does not have their own life cycle and identity and It cannot exist  alone without parent object.**

Whatever modifications such as create,update,delete happens to the parent object and it suppose to be taken place to the child objects as well . For example if I’m deleting a parent object , the deletion should not happen to the parent object alone but it should delete all this child object as well since those child object life cycle is entirely depends on the parent object . Their is a strategy called cascade in JPA and in Hibernate to enforce this methodology.

Coming back to your question. I assume Employee is your parent and phone is its child class. It does not make any point to leave the phone/child objects undeleted . Which is actually breaks the association methodology between objects.

**Still you can achieve the task by executing either HQL or native SQL quires but its not recommended to so .**

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Yes ok your answer is making sense when I am not using two entity's for the Employee and Phone at that time I need to use the embeddable as my phone Entity so that will not have their own life cycle the phone numbers is dependent on employee.But in my case, I have created two entity's for that reason.These two entity's are having their own life cycle.am I correct?

Comment: Rit. Is ter any specific design decision to keep the phone number alone alive? My point is their should be a way to identify the phone number is belongs to a person. having phone number active without having owner(employee) does'n not makes sense to me.

Comment: That will not make sense Ok.I have updated my code to new design of Class Entity and Student entity.If I delete the class the student should still alive right.To delete the student when deleting the class is not making sense to me.Thanks for your replay.

Comment: yes your right. In this scenario your designs looks perfect. Now you are making association of two entity(object has its own life cycle) ..In previous post you tried to make association between entity and a value type (object dont have its own life cycle)... Hope you have understood the difference between this two scenarios. Kindly close the thread if you got clear with your intended question.. Thanks!

Comment: I am not understood that how to delete the parent by making the child as null reference.

Comment: Null reference will not make any impact to hibernate engine.You simply delete the parent alone without using cascading...